# How can you invite people outside of Roblox to become friends / play with you?

Tags: roblox

I've looked through the iOS and Android apps extensively, but I cannot find a way to share a link that invites someone else to become your friend in Roblox. Similarly, there doesn't seem to be a way to share a link to invite someone to join you in our current game. This is a very common feature in mobile games and exists in e.g. Brawl Stars and PUBG. It's very helpful when inviting people in e.g. WhatsApp / Discord so they don't all have to type your name.

Is there any way to invite someone with a link to become your Roblox friend? Alternatively, is there any way to share a link to make them join your current game?

Did these features ever exist for Roblox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROBLOX has never supported a way to externally get someone to join your game, since it's required to own an account to play games. The same is true for friends.

There is no external option for adding a friend. You must type out the name or send a link to your profile.
The only external option for joining the same game is a private server link, but as it is private, only you and your friends will be in there.

For internal options, the party feature in Roblox's chat function (usually found on the bottom right of the screen) allows you to invite players to a game you are currently playing, but they must be on your friends list or in the party.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a friend or family member to play with you on Roblox, they have to create an account.

Once they are done creating their account, have them send you a friend request, either you or them.

After that, enjoy playing with each other!

## Inviting Friends by Game Link


To send an invite to your friend, you must join a game, click on the invite button (not all games allow you to invite your friends inside, so **have them join your server.** There is a specific server where your in that your friend will see you: "1 out of 10 friends in this server: *Your username*), then look for your name and click invite. In your friends' chat, it will see a game specific server join (isn't a link, but similar), and it will have the game your inside, and the picture with a "Join" button. Have your friend join you there. And then, enjoy playing!

## Friend Link by Message

Although you cannot do this on your "Messages" app, you can do it on Discord or Whatsapp.

**Discord:**
Log into Discord. Tell your friend: "Oh, hey! I am playing "your game"! Wanna join me?" They will respond commonly and you can do the steps in the title "Inviting Friends by Game Link".
**Whatsapp:**
Go on the "Whatsapp" app. Tell your friend that you are playing Roblox and when they respond, you can send them the game link or have them create an account and play with you, following the steps from: "Inviting Friends by Game Link".

---

> When you send your friend the invite, you can easily look into the link you send by hovering and staying on the invite button (doesn't work for all games)

---

Hope this helped inviting your friends!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry there is no feature for this, but if you're old enough for discord you can ask one of your friends to create a roblox account and play with you on roblox